# remove odd numbers

Tags: c++

I need to resolve this problme "Write a recursive function called removeCharge that receives an N number and returns a number that contains only the digits of the original number." I made it but now i don't know how to display the number in the same function.What can I do?

```
int newNumber=0;
int eliminareCifreImpare(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    eliminareCifreImpare(n/10);
    int c=n%10;
    if(c%2==0)
    newNumber=newNumber*10+c;
}
```

Comment: _"but now i don't know how to display the number"_ Didn't `std::cout << newNumber;` work for you?

Comment: It is a recursive function, outputting the result will have to be done from the root caller, not from within. @πάνταῥεῖ And for that, this function seems to be missing the vital `return` in the "else" branch.

Comment: A recursive function with correct returns from all branches will not require a global variable.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of the program which correctly creates the desired result and then only lacks an output. I ask because, admittedly, I have the impression that this is quite wild programming-by-chance and you are lacking the needed testable foundation for your attempts to write a correct function. And that makes this question too broad, for failing to provide a way of judging answers for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using a global variable because you don't properly understand how to return values from functions. You need to get a good understanding of how functions return values and how to use returned values before you try to write recursive functions.

Here's a working version

```
#include <iostream>

int eliminareCifreImpare(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    int newNumber = eliminareCifreImpare(n / 10);
    int c = n % 10;
    if (c % 2 == 0)
        newNumber = newNumber * 10 + c;
    return newNumber;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << eliminareCifreImpare(12345) << std::endl;
}
```